# file.aspx on ubuntu

Tags: mono

I'm changing my server from Microsoft to Ubuntu.  The current box hosts a website using an ASPX file ([www.seaserchne.com](http://www.seaserchne.com)).

I've imported all the files and structure, and can view the home page, however the side links don't exist in the Ubuntu version.

As I'm a complete newB to Linux, and not a web developer, have you any advice?  I've looked at installing Mono, but not 100% sure this will work, would I be better re-writing the website?

Thanks

S

Comment: What do you mean by "side links"?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run ASPX script on your server you must setup **Mono**.
In particular you must activate a particular module for apache (your http web server) providing access to mono environment, the **mod_mono** module.

You can fine a little help page in the Ubuntu Community Wiki: [Mod Mono](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ModMono)

If you don't want to setup mono on your server I suggest to rewrite your module using **PHP**, you can find a wiki on how to setup Apache to work with PHP here: [ApachePHPMySQL](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP)